# Error when trying to open folder with OpenFileDialog

Tags: vb.net, location, webdav, explorer, openfiledialog

In a form I have a button that launch a Windows Explorer to open a document. I try to open the folder where my file is located but I get this error:

[image: Open file error]

I get the same error when using InitialDirectory like so:

```
'Open Dialog to select file, only excel files can be selected(.xls, .xlsx, .xlsm)
 OpenFileDialog1.Reset()
 OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm"
 OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "https://stuff.ca/blabladocsdav/nodes/3175677/"
 OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
```

**But** I don't get the error if I paste the path in the address bar. When pasting the path in the address bar **I can select the file and open it**.

**EDIT 1**: Picture for visual
[image: Show result when working]

**EDIT 2**: I did some more testing: I can open or save a file if I give the specific path but I can't open the directory and let the user chose where to save it.
Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You can't open a URL in an `OpenFileDialog`.

Comment: `OpenFileDialog` is a dialog, *not* Explorer or Internet Explorer though it uses a window *like* Explorer.  It does not have browser capability (like the error says).  `how to solve`  download the file then open it

Comment: @EBrown Then why does it work when I paste the link?

Comment: What do you mean by *paste the link* - where?

Comment: @OneFineDay I added a picture to show you, if I paste the link in the "red rectangle" area it work.

Comment: As mentioned by @Plutonix the `OpenFileDialog` does not work the same as Windows Explorer. It will not navigate the web for you if you give it a URL.

Comment: @Alex If you look at the picture I posted..If I paste the URL in the `OpenFileDialog` adress bar it work like a Windows Explorer. Why?

Comment: @Plutonix I am not trying to access a webpage. This is as path to my files,   they are already on the server. Why would I download files I already have access to?

Comment: What happens if you set `OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory` to `https://stuff.ca/blablabla/nodes` (a shorter version of your original URL, i.e. one "directory" up)?

Comment: If you are trying to access a webdav server, you may want to use it's UNC path for the `InitialDirectory` field.

Comment: @Alex It won't work since this is actually a shorten URL using the ID for the last number

Comment: @Alex If I user the UNC path I get a windows explore error. Check the spelling and try again.